# Does sscanf modify the string passed to it?

Tags: c, glibc, scanf

Can I know if sscanf modifies the string passed to it. Or can anybody please point me where I can find the source code for sscanf ?

I downloaded glibc and found the following :

```
extern int sscanf (__const char *__restrict __s,
               __const char *__restrict __format, ...) __THROW;
extern int sscanf (__const char *__restrict __s,
               __const char *__restrict __format, ...) __THROW;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sscanf` never modifies the string you pass to it; you can tell by the `const` qualifier.

You can find the Glibc source code for `sscanf` on its [Gitweb](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/sscanf.c;h=0787b59a3f1d421910fcf3866a4997529834cfa5;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) . I was so stupid that I didnot observer the prototype. Thanks for the link where I cam find the source code.

Comment: @somasekhar - If this answer is correct, would you please consider 'accepting' it? Cheers!

Comment: sorry Arjun , last time when i tried to accept , it asked me to wait for 12 min more.  :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of good C resources. For `glibc`, the [GNU C Library Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/) should be your bible. Also in general, finding the documentation for a specific command, Googling "man command" will usually get you what you're looking for pretty quickly.

More specifically for `sscanf()`, the GNU C Library Manuals says explicitly,

> The behavior of this function is undefined if copying takes place between objects that
>   overlap—for example, if s is also given as an argument to receive a string read under
>   control of the ‘%s’, ‘%S’, or ‘%[’ conversion.

So, typically it wouldn't do anything, but if you do some squirrelly self-referencing between the string you're reading and the variables you're assigning to, it will have undefined behaviors.